# Connecting to MSSQL through Web service. Python. Suds. SOAP

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I'm connecting to web service using suds.

```
from suds.client import Client

 client=Client(url)

 #then i'm using web servise methods to get table. It is very big table.

 big_table=client.service.GetVeryBigTable()

 #nd trying read every row

 for row in big_table:
     print row.Id + row.Nmae + row.Description + row.Item1 +......
```

the question is - When i'm reading row, is it goes from my local memory, or it read every time from remote webservise?
I mean variable `big_table` contain link to all table in my memory or it take it every time from remote like iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no one know answer on this question. I figured out it by my own.

When method gives answer it is loading all the data in my local memory in XML format. So when I try to get big result. For example Some big table than it broke the connection an i gives me Error: that remote server close connection.

Only way in my case is to get IDs first, than make request for every row Using iteration of IDs.